# Invoke a Service even when the Device is Switched Off

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on a Security application, where i need to play siren music on receiving certain text(say **"siren"**).

So far, I've been able to receive the SMS intent and play the .mp3 siren music. But the problem encounters when the device is switched off.

Its been to my knowledge that there are some Intents(dont know what exactly to call them), those intents are fired even when the Device is switched off, just like the Scheduled Alarms (which executes even when the phone is switched off)

If anyone knows about those services or whatever they are, it would be helpfull if you share those ideas.

Comment: if the device is switched off nothing will ever happen. Specially receiving SMSs. Probably what you mean is that the device is in sleep mode, which can be awaked using methods describes on the answers.

Comment: but i have seen application, which play siren on receiving sms even when device is **switched off**, not in **sleep mode**.

Comment: No it doesn't. When the device is switched off is pretty much the same as having the battery removed. The crystal is not sending a clock to the processor (which makes it not do anything), all the radios are turned off, the android framework is not on the device RAM, the linux kernel is not on the device RAM. Do you have a link to this application?

Comment: I'll definitely post a link to that(a friend of mine has the application). but you might have heard about alarms, which are executed on time, even when the phone is switched off.

Comment: I'll be very much waiting for this link because from my years of experience as an electrical and controls engineer and software developer I'm sure that is physically impossible.

Comment: sure, but there might be phenomenon working behind the alarms and the system date time, which are correct even when we keep the switched off for long time. i have heard some CMOS cells which maintains those tasks even when the battery is discharged or phone is switched off.

Comment: Just make sure to let me know whenever you have the link, please.

Comment: not posible without root/custom ROM/special hardware http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20392/alarm-which-could-ring-even-when-device-is-off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need device to be awaken when you do your tasks, then simply wake it up using [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). Please note that once your `onReceive()` is completed device may fall back to sleep, so if you spawn some other processed in your `BroadcastReceiver`, you need to hold WakeLock.

You may take a look at this as well: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: whether it would be possible to wake the device on receiving sms through this broadcast receiver.?

Comment: When you receive SMS your BroadcastDevice is called (which indicates device is not sleeping, however the screen may be off). And while in your `onReceive()` you may do what you want, including fully awaking the device

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help.. Shouldn't be that hard to do but how can you get a text message if the phone is turned off?!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: I have seen an appliaction from google play store, through which you can play siren on your phone by sending some text to your phone, even when it is switched off.

Comment: By "off" OP means "sleeping". Not power-off